# Getting error on installing playsound package in python 3.11.4

Tags: python, pip

[this is the error that shows on entering the pip install package]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX7uW.png)

I've been attempting to install the playsound package using pip, and it's been quite a challenge. I'm currently working with Python 3.11 on a Windows 11 machine. However, each time I try to install the package, I'm faced with a persistent error that's becoming increasingly frustrating.

The error message I'm encountering is: "Subprocess exited with an error." Unfortunately, this error message doesn't provide much context or guidance on what's causing the problem. It's like hitting a brick wall without knowing what's on the other side.

I've taken several steps to troubleshoot the issue. I've verified that my pip installation is up to date, and I've checked the compatibility of the playsound package with Python 3.11. I've even gone as far as creating a fresh virtual environment to isolate any potential conflicts, but the error persists.

I'm fairly confident that my network connection is stable and not causing the problem. Other packages install without a hitch, which makes this issue with playsound all the more perplexing.

I've scoured online forums, GitHub issues, and Python documentation to find a solution, but I've come up empty-handed so far. It's quite discouraging, as I have a project that requires the functionality provided by playsound.

If anyone out there has encountered a similar problem or has insights into how to resolve this "Subprocess exited with an error" issue specifically on Python 3.11 and Windows 11, I would greatly appreciate your input. This roadblock has slowed down my progress, and I'm eager to overcome it and continue with my work. Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.